# How to get the caller's class definition line number?

Tags: python, class, traceback, inspect

There are some packages which has some methods like `subscribe` or `add` which let user adds a customized callback function. For debug purpose and curiosity, I would like to know which function and which class in this package actually called my callback function later. So it would be nice if I have the line number of the class.

**Minimal working example**

```
# test.py
import inspect


class Foo: # line 5

    def caller(self):
        print("Hello from caller")
        b=Bar()
        b.func()

class Bar:

    def func(self):
        print("Hello from func")
        stack = inspect.stack()
        the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__.__name__
        the_method = stack[1][0].f_code.co_name
        # Need some help here to get value 5
        # To do
        # ...
        print(f"Called by {the_class}.{the_method}()")


f = Foo()
f.caller()
```

**Output:**

```
Hello from caller
Hello from func
Called by Foo.caller()
```

**Q:** Inside `func`, how to get value **5** which is line number of definition of `class Foo`? Ideally by `inspect` or other traceback magic, not by searching the string in file.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? What will you do with the line number?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I add more details about motivation.